# JAVA Rewriting in a file

Tags: java

I am trying to rewrite in a file, alongside with the other text in it(not overwrite). But i don't know how can i do it using the exception as my buffered reader lose his initialization.

```
BufferedReader br;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        String line ;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(line);
            }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedWriter bw;
    try {
        File file = new File("file.txt");
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt"));
        if(br.readLine() != null) //ERROR Local variable may have not been initialized
            bw.newLine();
        bw.write("Hello");
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your error occurs because when you catch exceptions you merely print stack traces, then allow execution to continue.  For example, if `new FileReader("file.txt")` throws a `FileNotFound` exception, then `br` will not have been initialized, but control will still eventually reach `br.readline()`.  Java is complaining about that possibility. It would be better to not catch those exceptions at all in the given scope.

Comment: Why don't you use `Files.newBufferedWriter()`?

Comment: So what can i do to reuse br ?(if it doesnt cause an exception )

Answer (score 0):

```
 ...
 try {
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("file.txt",true));
    if(br.readLine() != null) //ERROR Local variable may have not been initialized
 ...
```

Try that on for size. That "true" after file.txt means it will append to what file you've found.

Here's a [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) to the documentation. Take note of the last constructor for FileWriter.

```
BufferedReader br = null;
```

To fix your current error changing your first line to this would be how you do it. That reader however is not needed whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

FileWriter has the ability to set the append flag new FileWriter(file, append)

or if you want to use your version
Initialize the variable with null

```
BufferedReader br = null;
```

try with resource may be useful here as well, because it closes everything for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Initialize the variable to null.
Say first line as,

BufferedReader br = null;